# How to confirm the type of bonding taking place between two substances?

Tags: bond, spectroscopy, analytical-chemistry

For example ink on paper: how can I confirm that the bonding is van der Waals and not covalent? Similarly, the same question can be asked about other interaction such as hydrogen bonding, ionic bonding, etc.

Are there analytical or spectroscopic methods for this purpose?

Comment: In your example, you mention two mixtures (both the ink and the paper), rather than two pure chemicals. How would you differentiate bonding of the ink (solvent, dyes and pigments) to the cellulose, lignin, sizing and colorant (e.g. TiO2) of the paper? Do you expect one answer be the same for all?

Comment: @DrMoishePippik, I was addressing a real-life situation in which one needs to determine "what's going on". If there are several methods one can use to determine the presence of either interaction, that would be helpful.

Comment: as written, your question is unanswerable because there are many different components in bot the ink and the paper, and for each pair the answer could be different, and you request one answer..